PostUp скрипт wireguard часто работает неправильно
PostUp скрипт в файле wg0.conf периодически работает неправильно (в 60% случает примерно).
В скрипте указано:
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.2 -p udp -m udp -d 10.10.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.10.1.2

Но в iptables я фактически вижу:
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 52 packets, 8705 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 SNAT       udp  --  any    any     192.168.0.0/24       10.10.10.0/24        to:10.10.10.22

Хотя должно быть:
0     0 SNAT       udp  --  any    any     192.168.0.2          10.10.1.0/24         udp to:10.10.1.2

Вместо 10.10.1.0/24 я получаю 10.10.10.0/24, а вместо 10.10.1.2 получаю 10.10.10.22
Я копирую строку из конфигурационного файла и выполняю, чтобы проверить - и вижу правильную запись в iptables.
Или перезапускаю службу wireguard и вижу что рядом появилась правильная запись, т.е. при перезапуске все работает нормально.
Почему-то именно при автостарте wireguard происходит такая ошибка, и то, иногда срабатывает правильно.
